# How to return UTF with re:replace

Tags: regex, utf-8, erlang

I'm trying to remove newline character in a string.

I tried this :

```
remove_newline(Data) ->
  re:replace(Data, "\n", "").
```

but it seems to return an ISO-8859 string.

I tried this too :

```
remove_newline(Data) ->
  {ok, MP} = re:compile("\n", [unicode]),
  re:replace(Data, MP, "").
```

but it doesn't work either.

*Data* comes from a *file:read_line* an is UTF encoded.

How to get an UTF string from re:replace ?

Comment: You can try this: `re:replace(Text, "\\n+", "", [global]).`

Comment: I tried, but it didn't make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is probably because you get the result as a list. You may need to use `re:replace(Data, "\n", "", [global, {return, binary}])`. Just look at documentation. http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#replace-4

Comment: I use a list because I have to use string:tokens in further processing. However i used `binary:bin_to_list` on this and then it worked. Thank you.
`remove_newline(Data) ->
  binary:bin_to_list(re:replace(Data, "\n+", "", [global, {return, binary}])). `

Comment: So you wanted a list of utf8 bytes. This is pretty uncommon and quite confusing. You might as well try `binary:split` on binary instead of `string:tokens`. This would help to keep standard invariants: utf8 in binaries, and unicode codepoints in lists.